# Changing the whitespace before the List of Schemes header

Tags: table-of-contents, vertical-alignment, chemstyle

I'm using chemstyle to create a list of schemes and also tocloft. I noticed that the whitespace above the List of Schemes header is larger than the whitespace above the Table of Contents and List of Figures headers. Is there a way to customize the whitespace above the los header (or the toc and lof headers) so it's consistent?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[oneside, 12pt, a4paper]{book} 
\setlength\headheight{15pt}
\usepackage[varioref=false]{chemstyle}
\usepackage{caption} %required for chemstyle
\usepackage{psfrag}
\usepackage{tocloft}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\tableofcontents
\cleardoublepage
\listoffigures
\cleardoublepage
\listofschemes

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: Does my answer solve your problem?

Comment: Yes, your solution works as expected for me. Thanks very much for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The culprit of this behavior is the `tocloft` package.

Adding the option `titles` when loading it:

```
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
```

causes the titles of the custom lists to be typeset using the default LaTeX methods, and so your problem is resolved.

MWE (note that there's no need to load `caption` since it is loaded by `chemstyle`):

```
\documentclass[oneside, 12pt, a4paper]{book}
\setlength\headheight{15pt}
\usepackage[varioref=false]{chemstyle}
\usepackage{psfrag}
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\tableofcontents
\cleardoublepage
\listoffigures
\cleardoublepage
\listofschemes

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]